# control high text contrast font in Android Accessibility

Tags: accessibility, accessibilityservice

i want enable/disable high text contrast font in Android Accessibility?

i were tried
`AccessibilityManager.getInstance(this).apply {     highTextContrastEnabled = true  } val isHighContrastEnabled = AccessibilityManager.getInstance(this).isHighTextContrastEnabled`
or

---

`val colorFilter = AccessibilityServiceInfo.ColorMatrixBuilder() .setColorMatrix(ColorMatrix().apply { setSaturation(0f) }) .build() info.flags = info.flags or AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS info.filter?.setColorFilter(colorFilter)`

`info.flags = info.flags or AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS info.fontScale = 1.5f`